# Regular expression to match text both inside and outside of parentheses

Tags: regex

I can't figure out how to match text both inside and outside of parentheses.

```
aaaa(bbbb)cccc(dddd()eeee)()fff(
```

=>

- aaaa
- bbbb
- cccc
- dddd(
- eeee)
- *empty string*
- ffff(

Text inside the parentheses: everything between the first opening and the nearest (!) closing parenthesis.

Text outside: everything else.

Inside text can contain `(`, outside text can contain both `(` and `)`, see the example above.

I'm matching the text inside with `\(.*?\)`. Empty inside is allowed.

I can't figure out how the match the remaining part (text outside).

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: Why is `(` captured with `dddd` but not with `aaaa`?

Comment: Try splitting with `\(([^)]*)\)`.

Comment: "aaaa" is outside of any parentheses. "dddd(" is between "(" and  the nearest closing parenthesis.

Comment: The input is just an example. It's a simplification of a much more complex problem :)

Comment: _""dddd(" is between "(" and the nearest closing parenthesis"_ - That doesn't sounds right. Which `(` and nearest `)` is it between? `(dddd()`? So, for those empty `()` you don't have the same matching rules as in the empty `()` preceeding `fff`? It seem very odd.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex:

[`\(([^)]*)\)|(?!$)([^(]*(?:[^)]+$)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/x2qs34/1)

This will also capture the parentheses that you want to skip, but the capture *groups* exclude them, so you could rely on those instead of the complete matches.